# Custom Form-Request dosen't work as expected- Backpack

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I'm creating a user management in Laravel using Backpack package, the main functionallity works well, I mean, you can create new users and then log in with them and deleteor edit them. But there is an aspect that dosent works as I want it. **The problem is that when you edit it you must insert a password too to save the edits**, this is not correct because you can not modify the password. To solve this, following the [BackPack documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-create#validating-fields-using-formrequests) I separate the *UserRequest*, so now I have two: *UserRequest* & *EditUserRequest*.
Nevertheless, the form still mark as required the password field, it seems that it pass trhough the setupCreateOperation function even if I click on edit the user.

I upload some images with the code and what appears me in the screen:

**UserCrudController.php**

```
 <?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\EditUserRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;

/**
 * Class UserCrudController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Admin
 * @property-read \Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel $crud
 */
class UserCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    /**
     * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\User::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/user');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('user', 'users');
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::column('name');
        CRUD::column('email');
        CRUD::column('password');

        /**
         * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']); 
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(UserRequest::class);
        //dd('setupCreateOperation');
        CRUD::field('name');
        CRUD::field('email');
        CRUD::field('password');

        /**
         * Fields can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
         * - CRUD::field('price')->type('number');
         * - CRUD::addField(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number'])); 
         */
    }

    /**
     * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
     * 
     * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        //dd('setupUpdateOperation');
        $this->crud->setValidation(EditUserRequest::class);
        $this->crud->setRequest($this->handlePasswordInput($this->crud->getRequest()));
        $this->crud->unsetValidation(); // validation has already been run

        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }

        /**
     * Handle password input fields.
     */
    protected function handlePasswordInput($request)
    {
        // Encrypt password if specified.
        if ($request->input('password')) {
            //dd($request->input('password'));
            $request->request->set('password', Hash::make($request->input('password')));
        } else {
            //si no lo mete el usuario que no lo tenga en cuenta
            $request->request->remove('password');
        }

        return $request;
    }
}
```

---

**UserRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // only allow updates if the user is logged in
        return backpack_auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required','min:5','max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'], // This is the diference
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation messages that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

---

**EditUserRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EditUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // only allow updates if the user is logged in
        return backpack_auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required','min:5','max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'password' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:8'], // this is the difference
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation attributes that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation messages that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: In you EditUserRequest, you need to remove rules for password so that it will not consider password as required. You also need to remove password from UI too.

Comment: @Bhushan you mean to remove the complete line of the password in the EditUserController? The thing is that i don't want to remove the password from the edit UI, because I want to let the user be able to change the password if he/she want it.

Comment: Did you replaced UpdateRequest with EditUserRequest inside controller to use that validation rule?

Comment: If you mean to make it as in the decumentation where it give it an "alias" and used it, I done it now and still dosent' work as I expected.

Comment: You mean that you created your custom User crud class which extends Backpack class and aliased your class for User crud?

Comment: The process I follow is the next one; I create a backpack CRUD for User table and all works fine, the main actions works. But now I want to cover the possibility that when you want to edit a User you are not force to introduce the password again. So thats why I create 2 form-requests, one for the create: UserRequest & EditUserRequest. The problem is that in the "edit" action is still taking the UserRequest instead of the EditUserRequest, and appears me the red asterisk.

Comment: I hope this will clear more my problem

Comment: Is it successfully calling setupUpdateOperation method when updating a user?

Comment: Yes, I found my error, is quite dummy XD. In the setupUpdateOperation() function i'm colling at the end the setupCreateOperation() function. Also I'm calling to unsetValidation() and this will also make my code don't work as I expected. If you want post this as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks for your help & interest :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `setupCreateOperation()` at the end of your `setupUpdateOperation()` then the CreateRequest will override the UpdateRequest. What you can do instead is do that first:

```php
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
        $this->crud->setValidation(EditUserRequest::class);
    }
```